# How to insert empty row and get autoincrement id?

Tags: java, psql

I want to add an empty row into my table and get the autoincrement id back in java. Im not sure why but im still getting userId=0. 
My java class:

```
public class UserProfileDao {
    private DBConnectionManager connectionManager;
    private static final String INSERT_USER = "insert into user_profile values(default)";
    private int userId;

    public UserProfileDao(DBConnectionManager connectionManager) {
        this.connectionManager = connectionManager;
        try (Connection connection = connectionManager.getConnection()) {
            try (PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement(INSERT_USER)) {
                try (ResultSet generatedKey = preparedStatement.getGeneratedKeys()) {
                    if (generatedKey.next()) {
                        userId = generatedKey.getInt(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    public int getUserId() {
        return userId;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:
[LASTVAL()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/interactive/functions-sequence.html) as next statement in the current session and get the value